# how do I run doxywizard?

Tags: doxygen

I have successfully downloaded and installed doxygen. I am trying to run doxygen but am a little overwhelmed by the configuration file. I see that there is a utility called doxywizard that guides you through the creation of a configuration file. How do I run this wizard? I see that there is a folder called Doxywizard. Do I run one of the files in this folder?

Comment: Other than the *potential* likelihood that you're wanting to doxygen C++ source files, what does C++ have to do with this question?

Comment: @WhozCraig fair enough. i removed the tag.

Comment: No worries. its a good question. I remember fighting with this on my Mac for awhile. Sorry i can't recall how it finally finished up, or I'd step up. The config UI is a little daunting, you're quite correct. The site wasn't a ton of help either, but trial and error more than anything got me what i needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you *successfully* installed doxygen, then you can run Doxywizard by typing `doxywizard` in terminal. I think, by default it goes into `/usr/local/bin/`.

EDIT: The official `.dmg` file for MacOS from the [doxygen download page](http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html) does contain the GUI front-end (`doxywizard`).

When building from source, according to the [doxygen user manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/install.html), one must use `configure --with-doxywizard` to enable `doxywizard` (also, note requirement for Qt version).

Comment: I can run the command doxygen at the terminal. But if I type doxywizard at the terminal, then I get command not found

Comment: What system are you on?

Comment: It should be just `doxywizard`, at least for linux distros.... Did you try running `doxygen` icon? Does window appear? If so, does it have `Wizard` button?... _Optionally, the executable doxywizard can be used, which is a graphical front-end for editing the configuration file that is used by doxygen and for running doxygen in a graphical environment. For Mac OS X doxywizard will be started by clicking on the Doxygen application icon._ This is from http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/starting.html

Comment: Did you download it from http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/download.html ? It says for Mac OS download: _This is a self-contained disk image, which contains the GUI frontend. The binaries support the whole range of Intel CPUs (both 32 and 64 bit)._

Comment: I built from source from that site, which did not generate the gui. But when I downloaded the .dmg everything worked. Want to update your answer so I can accept?

Comment: @abe3 Updated. When building from source, one needs to use `configure --with-doxywizard`, according to http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/install.html

Answer (score 13):

`brew install doxygen --with-graphviz --with-qt --with-llvm`

EDIT:

The command used to be:

`brew install doxygen --with-dot --with-doxywizard --with-libclang`

Comment: Besides the fact this takes **forever** (since it's building LLVM), this is the correct solution on MacOSX.

Comment: Now you must use `brew install doxygen --with-graphviz --with-qt --with-llvm` because `--with-dot`, `--with-doxywizard` and `--with-libclang`were deprecated.

Comment: `Error: invalid option: --with-graphviz`

Answer (score 0):

On Debian 10 I had to:

```
sudo apt install doxygen-gui
```

Then I can run doxywizard from the cmd line.